# What is the meaning of "$X \mapsto AX$ is a surjective mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

If square matrix $A$ has determinant $1$, then $X \mapsto AX$ is a surjective mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What does $X \mapsto AX$ mean??

Is it equivalent to say $T(x)=Ax$?

Comment: Yes. Take $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, now map it by the function $T(X) = AX$.

Comment: Yes. One uses $z\mapsto f(z)$ to say $f$ is the function that sends $z$ to the element $f(z)$. In this case the vector $X$ is sent to $AX$.

Comment: So, If X->AX , it means that T maps x in R^n to some vector in R^n?

Comment: confused between transformation and matrix notation

Comment: A matrix isn't a transformation. Multiplication by a matrix is a transformation. The notation "$x \mapsto Ax$" refers to a kind of "anonymous" function, which acts on its domain by multiplication by $A$. A more detailed way to notate this might be: $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n; \,\,\,\, x\mapsto Ax$, which is read as "$T$ is a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $T(x)$ is given by $A(x)$." (The second way makes mention of the name of the transformation and makes it clear that "$T(x) = Ax$" follows from the definition of $T$, and mentions the domain/range.)

Answer (score -1):

Because then $A$ would be invertible, and for a given $Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have: $X = A^{-1}Y$, then $T(X) = T(A^{-1}Y) = AA^{-1}Y = I_nY = Y$, showing $T$ is surjective.